# how are chained promises queued in microtasks queue

Tags: javascript, promise, event-loop

```
(async function() {
    var a,b;

    function flush(){
        return new Promise(res => {
            res(123)
    })}

    Promise.resolve().then(() => a = 1)
    Promise.resolve().then(() => b = 2)

    await flush();

    console.log(a)
    console.log(b)

})()
```

In this snippet, the value of `a` and `b` gets logged in the console.

```
(async function() {
    var a;
    var b;

    function flush(){
        return new Promise(res => {
            res(123)
    })}

    Promise.resolve().then(() => a = 1).then(() => b = 2)   

    await flush();

    console.log(a)
    console.log(b)

})()
```

In this case the value of `a` gets logged as 1, whereas `b` is undefined.

```
(async function() {
    var a;
    var b;

    function flush(){
        return new Promise(res => {
            setTimeout(res)
    })}

    Promise.resolve().then(() => a = 1).then(() => b = 2)   

    await flush();

    console.log(a)
    console.log(b)

})()
```

This gives the same result as the first snippet, with the value `a` as 1 and `b` as 2

I would like to understand, why does promise chaining behaves differently than multiple individual promises

PS: I have a basic understanding of microtask queueing and the event loop.

Comment: Both of these give me the same output in Firefox 68. EDIT: also in Chrome 75 EDIT2: same in Node node v10.16.0 - tested both [here](https://repl.it/languages/nodejs) - [code block 1](https://repl.it/repls/FreshThornyCommand) [code block 2](https://repl.it/repls/DependentWhichAddition)

Comment: @VLAZ, I have edited the question, I hope this more clear, let me know if further clarification is needed.

Comment: All three code blocks produce the same for me, none of them produces `undefined`: [one](https://repl.it/repls/WeirdAgreeableClass) [two](https://repl.it/repls/ShamelessSecondaryEmulators) [three](https://repl.it/repls/VerticalShortProjections)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running Node 12.3.1, I can reproduce the observation stated in the question,
after changing `setTimeout(res(123))` to `setTimeout(() => res(123))`.

In JavaScript the concurrency model is the event loop, in which the single thread executes callbacks from a queue.

---

In the first snippet, the following happens.

1. Since the promise is reoslved, `.then` adds the callback `() => a = 1` to the queue.
2. `() => b = 2` is added to the queue.
3. The code after the await<sup>1</sup> `() => console.log(a); console.log(b)`<sup>2</sup> is added to the queue.
4. The callback in step 1 is run, `a` is set to 1
5. `b` is set to 2
6. `a` and `b` logged.

Since setting the variables happens before printing them, you see both 1 and 2.

---

In the second snippet:

1. The callback `() => a = 1` is added to the queue by `.then`
2. The first `.then` returns a new promise, which is not resolved, as the first callback is not run yet. Then second `.then` attaches `() => b = 2` to the pending promise.
3. The code after the await `() => console.log(a); console.log(b)` is added to the queue.
4. The callback `() => a = 1` is run, and fulfills the promise created in step 2. That causes `() => b = 2` to be added to the queue.
5. `a` and `b` logged.
6. `b = 2` is run, but this happens after `b`, which was `undefined`, got printed.

---

In Firefox however, the output of all three snippets are the same.
I managed to produce the above behaviour by adding an `async`.
`Promise.resolve().then(async () => a = 1).then(() => b = 2)`

Here is a simplified that exhibits the same problem.
1 5 2 3 4 in Node but 1 2 3 5 4 in Firefox.

```
(async function() {
  Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => console.log(1))
    .then(() => console.log(2))
    .then(() => console.log(3))
    .then(() => console.log(4))
  await Promise.resolve()
  console.log(5)
})()
```

But if you change the `await` to `.then`,
`Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(5))`

You get 1 5 2 3 4 in both platforms.<sup>3</sup>

Why? I googled and found this: https://v8.dev/blog/fast-async

Node 12 optimizes away some extra steps with `await`, which previously required an extra throwaway promise, and two more microticks. That seems to be the reason "5" comes two steps earlier in Node 12.

---

1. You can have the simplified mental model that `await` turns the rest of the code into a callback.
2. In fact "the rest of the code" also resolves the promise created by the async function.
3. Huh, so `.then` and `await` are different after all.